# Пустая строка в Scanner java

Tags: java, scanner

Как в куске следующего кода разрешить не вводить `middleName`? Когда я просто нажимаю Enter, переход к следующему действию не происходит.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
String surname;
String middleName;
String address;
String joinDate;

System.out.print("Add new employee\nEnter employee name: ");
name = in.next();

System.out.print("Enter employee surname: ");
surname = in.next();

 System.out.print("Enter employee middle name: ");
 middleName = in.next();
 System.out.print("Enter employee address: ");
 address = in.next();
```

этот код не помог

```
if (in.hasNextLine()) {
    middleName = in.next();
} else {
    middleName = null;
}
```

Comment: а чем определяется `разрешить не вводить`? то есть просто enter нажал человек и перешел к вводу адреса? или дать где-то возможность вообще даже не переходить к пункту `enter employee middle name`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Дать возможность нажать enter, тем самым у сотрудника будет null middlename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал не использовать для такого ввода `Scanner`. Используйте `BufferedReader`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter employee middle name: ");
        final String middleName = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("middleName = '" + middleName + "'");
    }
}
```

Если, тем не менее, очень хочется использовать `Scanner`, то хотя бы используйте его правильно, т.е. метод [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--),  а не [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter employee middle name: ");
        final String middleName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("middleName = '" + middleName + "'");
    }
}
```